# Why can't I install Windows update KB3000061?

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to install [KB3000061](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3000061), but after the installation Windows is always reverting the changes and the update isn't installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Technet forum post [KB3000061 fails to install on Server 2012](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f77691d8-a9d0-4714-98ad-71665cfa8965/kb3000061-fails-to-install-on-server-2012), you should delete the following registry key:

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers\{e7ef96be-969f-414f-97d7-3ddb7b558ccc}`

Then reboot your machine and try to install KB3000061 again.